Empirical concentration of sum of Bernoulli variables around unknown expectation
Setup Let $S_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ where $X_i\in \{ 0,1 \}$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli's with some unknown probability $p\in[0,1]$.
We want to provide concentration for $S_n$ around its mean $p$ (i.e., $\mathbb{P}[| S_n - \mathbb{E}[S_n]| \ge \varepsilon]\le \delta$) using the smallest $n$ possible.
Standard Hoeffding based arguments yield that for a given $\varepsilon$ one can set $n\ge\frac{1}{2\varepsilon^2} \log(2/\delta)$.
My approach is to rely on the empirical process to test if for a given $n$ the estimate $S_n$ is close to its expectation leveraging the results by Maurer and Pontil which states that for a given $n$ we can bound $$ \mathbb{P}\left[\left|S_n-\mathbb{E}[S_n] \ge \hat{\varepsilon}\right| \right] \le \delta, \hat{\varepsilon} = \sqrt{\frac{2V(S_n) \ln(4/\delta)}{n}} + \frac{7\ln(4/\delta)}{3(n-1)}, V(S_n) = \frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{i<j} (X_i-X_j)^2$$
Where the above can be interpreted as follows,

if the sample variance $V(S_n)$ is close to $0$ then the bound converges as $n\ge O(\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \log(2/\delta))$ (which is $O(1/\varepsilon)$ sharper than standard Hoeffding's), while
when the sample variance is large (i.e., $V(S_n)\approx 0.25$ by a well known inequality) such bound essentially recovers the one with Hoeffding.

Therefore we have the following cases.

When the unknown mean is close to $0$ or $1$, the empirical bound is
very sharp (leading to a small sample size $n$ to estimate it)
When the unknown mean is close to $0.5$ the variance $V(S_n)$ is close to $0.25$ and we gain nothing by using the ''empirical'' values.

Question As for values of the unknown mean $\mathbb{E}[S_n]\approx 0.5$ we expect half of the samples ($X_i, i=1,\dots,n$) to be $0$ and the other ones to be $1$, but this yields to a maximal variance of $0.25$, are there better arguments that we can leverage still based on the empirical quantities to prove concentration ? (maybe something like an empirical McDiarmid inequality), any reference can be helpful!
